# select_tag options_for_select, default value not getting set

Tags: ruby-on-rails

the rendered html:

```
<select id="version_filter" name="version_filter">
<option value="2">Current Version</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
</select>
```

the select_tag

```
<%= select_tag "version_filter", 
        options_for_select(@version_select, @selected_version.to_s) %>
```

I through an alert into my page to see if the @selected_version even exists:

```
alert("<%= @selected_version.to_s %>");
```

and it does. the @selected_version is 0, but when the page loads, the drop down select thing shows "Current Version" as the selected value.

Rails isn't complaining about the syntax, so, how do I get not-the-first-value to be the defaultly selected?

Comment: Are the values in `@version_select` integers or strings?  If they are values than the string value of `@selected_version` will not be equal.

Comment: @version_select is a 2d array of ints. I'll try dropping the .to_s UPDATE: didn't work, same behavior as in question.

Comment: UPDATE 2: turns out I had to do .to_i o.o

Comment: @TheLindyHop please post that solution and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to make sure that @selected_version was of the same type as the item I was trying to match it to in @version_select.

Since @version_select, in this case, is a 2D array of ints,

```
@selected_version needs to have .to_i instead of .to_s
```